# How to get top indices of float array in C and pairing it with strings stored in an another array

Tags: c, indices

I updated the code to find top 5 indices of a float array. Some
 how it is only updating top[0]th element for max indices. In the
 mentioned example below max indices is like below top[0] = 9, top[1]
 =7, top[2]=5 and so on. But it is updating top[0] only.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    double *arr =malloc(sizeof(double)*10);
    int N=10;
    int n =5;
    int *top =malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    arr[0] = 0.123; 
    arr[1] = 0.345;
    arr[2] = 0.445;
    arr[3] = 0.545;
    arr[4] = 0.645;
    arr[5] = 0.745;
    arr[6] = 0.542;
    arr[7] = 0.945;
    arr[8] = 0.145;
    arr[9] = 0.995;
    int top_count = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<N;++i) {
        // invariant: arr[top[0]] >= arr[top[1]] >= .... >= arr[top[top_count-1]]
        // are the indices of the top_count larger values in arr[0],...,arr[i-1]
        // top_count = max(i,n);
        int k;
        for (k=top_count;k>0 && arr[i]>arr[top[k-1]];k--);
        // i should be inserted in position k
        if (k>=n) continue; // element arr[i] is not in the top n
        // shift elements from k to top_count
        printf("6:: Iam here\n");fflush(stdout);
        int j=top_count;
        if (j>n-1) { // top array is already full
                j=n-1;
        } else { // increase top array
            top_count++;
        }

        for (;j>k;j--) {
            top[j]=top[j-1];
        }

        // insert i
        top[k] = i;
        printf("top[%0d] = %0d\n",k,top[k]);

        printf("top_count=%0d\n",top_count);
    }
    return top_count;
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And also please take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: However, one possible source of your problem is your use of  `&output` when calling `top_elems`. The expression `&output` gives you a pointer *to the pointer*, it is of type `double **`.

Comment: Write a separate function to insert a pair into the top-n list; it should make your program easier to read and debug.

Comment: Hmm, many compilation warnings. `tmp.c:47:34: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
    printf("\n Error: Coef File %s did not opened successfully\n");`
                                ~^
`tmp.c:55:11: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char **' to parameter of type 'char *'; remove & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    fgets(&labels_[i], 1024, fp1);`
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
etc.

Comment: Another possible source of problems is the variable `top` which is an uninitialized pointer, its value is *indeterminate*. There are probably quite a few more problems. I suggest you rebuild with the flags `-Wall` and `-Wextra`, and take a long look at the large list of warnings you're going to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int top_elems(double *arr, int N, int *top, int n);

int top_count = top_elems(&output, 10, top,5);
```

- `output` already decomposes to `double *` do you are passing the address_ of a pointer to `double` into a function that should take a pointer to double
- top is not initialised before the function call so is **undefined** the first use of it dereferences this undefined pointer
- ... yeah, I'm not going to go further.  your code has some serious but simple to spot issues.  If you had made a MCV example, you should have seen some of of them, instead of just dumping your code here.

After code changes:

> I updated question to update the top five indices of float array into top[] array. but it is only updating top[0]th element. anything wrong with the code?

Well, I updated the indentation of the code in the question to make it more readable.

You will notice that there is no indentation after this for loop:

```
for (k=top_count;k>0 && arr[i]>arr[top[k-1]];k--);
```

This is because the loop body of this loop is:

```
;
```

That's it.  it is just an empty statement that does nothing.  All the loop does is set variables, which are then modified in the rest of the code that follows, but as they are not within a loop, they are only executed the once.

As the loop goes from `top_count` down to `0`, it should be obvious why it is just the first index that is modified.

Comment: int *top =malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
I allocated memory for top and modified the code int top_count = top_elems(output, 10, top,5); I am still seeing segmentation error when I try to access top

Comment: @sathakiran have you stripped it down to a MVCE yet?  As suggested in the main comments, strip out the code to do the insert and put that in its own function, then test that in isolation.

Comment: I updated question to update the top five indices of float array into top[] array. but it is only updating top[0]th element. anything wrong with the code?

Comment: @sathyakiran answer updated.  But your modification of the question has rendered the first half of my answer senseless, as it is no longer able to refer to the question originally asked.  Please don't do that.

Comment: <pre> arr[0] = 0.623;
  arr[1] = 0.745;
  arr[2] = 0.440;
  arr[3] = 0.145;
  arr[4] = 0.645;
  arr[5] = 0.741;
  arr[6] = 0.542;
  arr[7] = 0.445;
  arr[8] = 0.145;
  arr[9] = 0.095;
For the above inputs, I am getting following output top[0] = 0
top[0] = 1
top[2] = 2
top[3] = 3
top[1] = 4
top[1] = 5
top[4] = 6, but, Expected output should be like below
top[0] = 1
top[1] = 5
top[2] = 4
top[3] = 0
top[4] = 6 output is not coming as expected for 2nd and 3rd elements.
</pre>